# Safari complains about SSL certificate on redirect page

Tags: ipad, safari, windows, ssl

I have gotten reports from people navigating to our site without entering the www. part of the URL that our SSL certificate does not match and so generates a warning. This is technically correct I suppose since our SSL certificate is for the www. domain and two other subdomains.

But I have a redirect function so that anyone who enters the non-www url gets instantly redirected to the www URL. I have tested this on several browsers and on android phones. It seems only on Safari have any problems been found. Anyone have any suggestions on why this is happening with Safari and how to avoid it? The server is a windows server running IIS.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do except get a new certificate which covers both www and non-www.

Any redirects will only be done after a successful SSL handshake. But since your certificate does not match the name in the URL used by the client there will be no successful SSL handshake and thus no redirect.